# Using Conditional Statement in functions.php

Tags: filters, conditional-tags

I've got this code below in my `functions.php` and I'd like to add two filters with conditional statement not to effect every query_posts. Something like this

```
if(!is_admin() && is_page('Home')){ //two filters }
```

However, I don't know PHP well enough to know where to put it or how to use the `<?php>` tags.
Can anyone advise? It is from [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-voting-post-ranking) that was closed in WP Forums.

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
add_filter('posts_join_paged','edit_posts_join_paged');

function edit_posts_join_paged($join_paged_statement) {
    global $wpdb;
    $join_paged_statement = "LEFT JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."wpv_voting ON ".$wpdb->prefix."wpv_voting.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID";
    return $join_paged_statement;
}

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby_statement = "(".$wpdb->prefix."wpv_voting.vote_count) DESC";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you put the second block into the first. And wait until the last moment:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_71899_start_filter' );

function wpse_71899_start_filter()
{
    // wrong page
    if ( ! is_page( 'Home' ) )
        return; // stop here.

    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
    add_filter('posts_join_paged','edit_posts_join_paged');
}

function edit_posts_join_paged($join_paged_statement) {
    global $wpdb;
    $join_paged_statement = "LEFT JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."wpv_voting ON ".$wpdb->prefix."wpv_voting.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID";
    return $join_paged_statement;
}

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby_statement = "(".$wpdb->prefix."wpv_voting.vote_count) DESC";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

In your theme’s `functions.php` should be only one `<?php` tag: at the first line.

You can place this code anywhere in that file, at the bottom for example.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I'm wondering how the final code should look. I'm not sure what the 71899 filter lines are?           

'wpse_71899_start_filter' );

function wpse_71899_start_filter()

Comment: `wpse_71899_start_filter()` is a safe name for the function. We use this prefix here to prevent collisions with other peoples code.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to use these little comment boxes to display the full code so I answered below. Once you give it a glance, I'm going to post that exact code below. I just replaced that number with dg_filter - not sure if there's restrictions on what a function can be named.  Thanks again!

Comment: IS there a way to past code into these comment boxes?

If I paste the code I originally posted into functions.php, it works, but if I paste the suggested code with function wpse_71899_start_filter(), it breaks the category view. Thanks again!

Comment: Category pages are not affected due to the `if ( ! is_page( 'Home' ) )`. No idea what went wrong. Edit your question to document where you got stuck.

Comment: toscho, Thanks for keeping on showing up here. I tried posting your code in my functions.php and it indeed worked. The categories are working again! Not sure what I did wrong at first, but you really helped. Just one more question...if I wanted to sort the categories as well, how would I do that?

Comment: [Log the query](https://gist.github.com/4012007) for that and ask a new question including the query you want to change. You would have to change the `orderby` clause, but need to see the query.

Comment: Ah shoot. After reviewing the site, it appears that the home page no longer sorts the blogs. It just displays them as if the code is not there at all.

Comment: So, although the suggested code no longer breaks the category view, the sort functionality does not work on the home page. My end goal would be to have it sort on the home page and category pages. Should I start a new question for this?

Comment: yes, I think so. Not sure why the filter is ignored.

Comment: I do appreciate your help. I posted a new question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73397/sorting-posts-by-vote-count-and-functions-php